# Error in KNN model which says number of columns must be same

Tags: r, knn

Hi I'm trying to implement a machine learning model using KNN.

```
KNN_Model <- function(train, test){
  
  set.seed(1738)
  
  train_y = train[,'prod_efficiency']
  train_x = train[, names(train) !='prod_efficiency']
  
  test_y = test[,'prod_efficiency']
  test_x = test[, names(test) !='prod_efficiency']
  knnmodel = knn.reg(train_x, train_y)
  
  print(test_x)
  pred_y = predict(knnmodel, test_x)
  
  
  MAE(y_pred, test_y)
  RMSE(y_pred, test_y)
  R2(y_pred, test_y, form = "traditional")
  
  x=1:length(test_y)
  plot(x, test_y,pch=19, col="blue")
  lines(x, y_pred, col="red")
  legend("topleft", legend = c("y-original", "y-predicted"),
         col = c("blue", "red"), pch = c(19,NA), lty = c(NA,1),  cex = 0.7)
  

}

KNN_Model(train, test)
```

But I'm keep getting the following error.
[image]

All the columns are correct. The same data split worked for Random forest model. Can someone please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `train` and `y` in `knn.reg`

```
knn.reg(train = train_x, y = train_y)
```